# French movies/videos with French subtitles

Tags: oral, ressources, mathématiques, apprentissage, cinéma

I would appreciate it if you would introduce me to some sources of free downloadable videos/films  in the French language accompanied by French subtitles (either treating of mathematics or of any general subject).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- There is an amazing site called [Les films français avec
  sous-titres](http://filmfra.com/) where one may find a plethora of films to watch of different genres (comedies, dramas, adventures and the like).
- Very useful: [TEDx chanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phwihXR3VSM&list=PLx5TmpeF4jNKZ4Ru22CwkFHHas0FX-kYa) in YouTube.
- Also: [French films with French subtitles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZF2IMAjetM8&list=PL4qTXMCCZ6Nijct0i4JdgVxU4OT086lHm) in
  YouTube.
- Yet another very useful site [cinema-dossier-pedagogique](http://flecampus.ning.com/profiles/blogs/cinema-dossier-pedagogique-fle).
- An old relevant discussion in [FSE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9069/are-there-any-sites-dedicated-to-having-french-subtitles-for-french-films) and another [one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-movies-or-tv-series-can-i-use-to-improve-my-french).

**EDIT**

Perfect is the enemy of good:-)! I found the following site a most comprehensive source. There is even a classification (B1,B2,C1 and the like):

http://www.linguo.tv/videos

Highly recommended. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  your answer.

Comment: @AliTaghavi : Avec plaisir ! If you think that either my reply or the other completely answer your question do not forget to mark it as an accepted answer. Of course this is not obligatory:-)!

Comment: Merci beaucoup  de  votre  message et  merci  encore  de  votre reponse. Voyez SVP  la  post  suivant  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-cant-i-accept-two-answers-to-the-same-question-simultaneously

Comment: merci  encore  de  votre reponse a  laquelle   je  ai donne +1(vote  positive) avec  mon plus  grand plaisir.

Comment: merci beaucoup pour votre edit recent(june 16)

Answer (score 6):

You have also really nice Youtube channels to learn (or improve) french for free among which:

1. [Learn French with Vincent](https://www.youtube.com/user/imagiers)

Vincent is a French teacher with his own [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/imagiers), and he will teach you thousands of phrases, as well as vocabulary, grammar and the correct pronunciation. He aims to take you from being a beginner in the language all the way to becoming an advanced French speaker. Listening to French is an excellent way of learning, and when viewing Vincent’s videos you can hear him speaking French. Vincent has another website where you can find out all about his services, and he is also offering lessons via Skype.

2. [JeFrench](https://www.youtube.com/user/jefrench10)

This site’s slogan is: “Learn French With Us…It’s Fun!” Having fun is always an aid and attraction to learning. The mini-lessons JeFrench offer cover all the basics of the language, and are easy to follow with recognisable images illustrating the subjects covered in their videos.

3. [FrenchPod101](https://www.youtube.com/user/frenchpod101)

FrenchPod101 is a very popular [YouTube video channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/frenchpod101) for learning French, and with good reason. FrenchPod101 has a very large selection of videos on so many different subjects that are important if you want a very balanced knowledge of the language. There are videos covering the use of adjectives, there is one that explains three ways of saying you love someone in French, and even a video all about French superstitions. The very slick presentations are in English and French.

[Source](https://www.ifalpes.com/blog/learn-french-with-youtube-now/)

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  and  +1 for  your  answer.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it helped ! :)

Comment: Both  answers are really very  nice  and  helpful and  I  wonder to  choose one  answer  to  accept.  please  read the  following  post  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-cant-i-accept-two-answers-to-the-same-question-simultaneously

Comment: I agree the other answer is really nice too, I have no Idea so, follow your heart ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

French in Action, la méthode Capretz (Yale, 1987) est toujours disponible sur [Annenberg Media](https://www.learner.org/resources/series83.html) et [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3nHCqa_eoU).  C'était le début de l'immersion.

Les leçons restent très utiles pour apprendre le français, puis ça devient du cinéma, réalisé à Paris dans les années 80s.  J'adore.

"This series uses active participation to increase fluency in French, while introducing French culture. Pierre Capretz's proven language-immersion method is presented within a humorous teleplay with native speakers of all ages and backgrounds. The storyline of an American student and a young Frenchwoman's adventures in Paris and the French countryside is reinforced by Dr. Capretz's on-camera instruction. The series is also appropriate for teacher professional development."

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre repons!

Answer (score 1):

I recently started searching for French movies with French subtitles to learn the language. Filmfra.com seems to be dead, but I found [LookMovie](https://lookmovie2.to/). Here you can find many movies in many different languages, French included.

For example, here's a [link](https://carouthfularki.monster/movies/play/the-mad-adventures-of-rabbi-jacob-1973?mid=17&sid=&sec=11702ad376c57caaa11d0788ccb28d86655354bd&t=1678637842) to Les Aventures de Rabbi Jacob, a great movie starring Louis de Funès. Simply press the subtitles button in the player and select your preference.

EDIT: They aren't downloadable, at least not easily. Perhaps you could download them by pasting the link into some downloader, or find the movie elsewhere and download the subtitles separately from [OpenSubtitles](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/subs).

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que Louis de Funès soit l'idéal pour apprendre le français !

Comment: Thank you very much for  your answer!

Comment: @Toto C'est vrais. Il parle tres vite et la prononciation n'est pas tres claire, mais ses films sonts tres amusants!