# Bonjour, Mon amis

Tags: vocabulaire

Mon francais est beaucoup miserable. Je suis une American qui voudrais parlez francais (better). Questce que le bonafide (way) (to learn quickly)? J'ai (tried) (reading threads) oh I give up. What is the best way to learn to read and write french quickly? Is it okay if I try to translate in a comment on another thread and wait for someone to correct me? I can pronounce most french well enough to read it to but I miss at least half the meaning. I studied french for three semesters but my vocabulary is still small. What is the best way to expand it? My apologies for posting in English on a french meta board. Please answer in french so I can practice.

Edit:
What are the classical or contemporary ways to learn French (or any language) quickly? For example immersion in speech, studying vocabulary lists, focusing on grammar and verb tenses, etc...

I am slowly reading your answers, I appreciate them all ;)

Comment: Welcome! You can ask questions in English or French on the site so no worries, although you should ask a specific question. Take the [tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour) and see the [help pages](https://french.stackexchange.com/help). There is also a [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) site you might want to explore. You may also ask questions in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) where your questions may be less specific and where you can ask for more general advice etc.

Comment: Take a look at these [questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apprentissage).

Comment: @Survenant9r7 merci pour le bienvenue grande.

Comment: It's okay to post in english, half of the questions here are from english speakers trying to understand grammar :) I learned english by watching series (sitcoms, South Park), and then I went to books, I guess the other way is similar. The main advice: don't try to translate word by word: try to get what the general meaning is, and you'll understand the words. If really you don't understand a sentence, just look at the important word (noun or verb), and try to read again.

Comment: See also this thread https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33988/french-movies-videos-with-french-subtitles/33989#33989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonjour, 
Je peux vous proposer de regarder les journaux d'actualités français comme  [le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/), ou [Courrier international](https://www.courrierinternational.com/) par exemple (Je ne vais pas tous les citer, il y en a tellement... ).

Si j'avais un conseil c'est également de ne pas oublier les accents en français, on en a dans beaucoup de mots.

Je peux vous aider en traduisant votre question en français :

Mon français n'est pas parfait. Je suis une Américaine qui voudrais mieux parler français (améliorer mon français). Quelle est la meilleure façon d'apprendre rapidement le français ? J'ai essayé de lire des discussions sur internet. Quelle est la meilleure façon d'apprendre à parler et écrire le français ? Est-ce que ça va si j'essaie de traduire un commentaire sur un autre fil pour attendre que quelqu'un me corrige ? J'arrive à lire la plupart des textes en français, mais j'en comprends la moitié. J'ai étudié le français durant trois semestres, mais mon vocabulaire reste pauvre. Quelle est la meilleure manière pour élargir mon vocabulaire en français ? Mes excuses pour poster en anglais dans un site français. S'il vous plaît répondez en français, pour que je m'exerce :).

Comment: Le monde et courrier international c'est pas super facile pour commencer à mon avis, il doit y avoir plus accessible.

Comment: Carrément d'accord avec @TeleportingGoat, c'est même du vocabulaire ciblé à destination des professionnels.

Comment: I can read most of your answer now, especially the part you translated, merci boku pour le traduction. Is there a guide to tenses somewhere handy? I still don't know future tense very well. I would up vote both answers given but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: @BugSquasher En France nous avons le bescherelle comme référence pour la conjugaison. https://bescherelle.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the best way to learn a new language is to practice.

For that, you have several ways. If you can distinguish the words when someone speaks the language, you can watch TV shows and movies in French (subtitled in English so as to compare).

If you manage to read basic sentences, social networks can help a lot (but not necessarily) since people aren't very talkative on them. Be careful about the mistakes though.

If you want to expand your vocabulary, consider simply writing sentences, and when you don't know the word you want to write, you translate it, **but learn about its origin**.  In French, almost any word has a root and is explained by similar words : if you understand the concept, then it's instantly easier to memorize it.

Comment: thank you mademoiselle. If I could see side by side translations of books or stories that would be ideal. Movies are too slow for learning but they would be good practice for hearing and pronunciation. I would up vote but not enough rep yet