# Best resources for improving French comprehension and speaking at B1 - B2 level fast

Tags: ressources

Sorry, if this is completely off topic:

I'm looking to the resources to improve my French at B1 - B2 level. Would prefer to concentrate on comprehension and speaking as I need to communicate with native speakers.

I took Pimsleur French 3 - 5, which was good, the vocabulary they drill you on is rather limited. What would be the best sources you could recommend for a faster progress?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37577/1893

Answer (score 1):

At B1-B2 level one should start switching from pedagogical texts to real books, films, songs, etc.  Admittedly, these can be of varying level of difficulty, so I give below a few suggestions that worked for me.

- Adapted texts, like "Alex Leroc" series. These are readable, but have disadvantages: a) not always interesting, and b) existing in limited quantities.
- Children books - these may be tricky, as, despite simple grammar, they may include a lot of non-trivial vocabulary specific to children. *Petit Nicolas* is a time-honored classic. So is *Le Petit Prince* (though I couldn't struggle through it as an adult.) So is Harry Potter series.
- "Junk literature" - like detective novels ("polars") in French, particularly those translated from other languages (and hence somewhat simpler ) *Millenium* is an excellent read, for example.
- TV series, particularly the highly repetitive ones, like *Hélène et les garçons*.
- Disney animated films (which are dubbed in French, usually with high quality translations of texts and songs.
- Eric Rohmer films, and generally *nouvelle vague* films - I was fortunate to be introduced to them by my French teacher. The accents might be a bit hard though